# Can I get an external display to have 10-bit color on a 2015 rMBP?

Tags: display, graphics, color

The setup is a 2015 13" Macbook Pro with Intel Iris Graphics 6100, connected via Displayport to a Dell U2711 (which is capable of 10-bit color.) The OS is Sierra.

Is there a way to get the external display to run in 10-bit color?

Comment: How do you know that it's currently not displaying colors in 10-bit per channel?

Comment: System information shows pixel depth as "32-Bit Color (ARGB8888)." There is a lot of conflicting information out there but if it was in 10-bit mode, it should show 30-bit color.

Comment: that's correct (30-bit)

Comment: Have you tried SwitchResX? It should allow you to set your display to "billions of colors." https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0SNd.png

Comment: I think there may be a UI bug in System Information where it shows the the depth.  Examine this test file in Preview to see the gradations.  My Dell UP3214Q shows as ARGB8888, but the gradient shows smooth, so I believe it's actually 10-bit.  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jursonovicst/gradient/master/gradient.png